# What does "this" refer to exactly in this code?

Tags: java, linked-list, this

```
public CharList(CharList l) 
{
    // Whatever method your CharList provides to get the 
    // first node in the list goes here
    CharNode pt = l.head(); 

    // create a new head node for *this* list
    CharNode newNode = new CharNode();
    this.head = newNode;

    // Go through old list, copy data, create new nodes 
    // for this list.
    while(pt != null)
    {
        newNode.setCharacter(pt.getCharacter());
        pt = pt.getNext();
        if (pt != null)
        {
            newNode.setNext(new CharNode());
            newNode = newNode.getNext();
        }

    }
}
```

I thought that this is used to refer to the Object A as in "A.addElement(car);", but in this case I don't know what this refers to... And I don't see the point in doing:         this.head = newNode; since this.head is never used again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the keyword "this" in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577575/using-the-keyword-this-in-java)

Comment: this line doesn't make sense: newNode = newNode.getNext();  It should have been newNode = pt;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the current instance of `CharList`, and `this.head` refers to the instance field `head`. You can discard `this` keyword to access instance fields if there are no local variables with the same name.

Comment: by current instance do you mean the charlist that is passed as a variable or that the method is creating?

Comment: @user2089523 I mean the instance that is created by calling the constructor. So, for example, if you have `CharList c = new CharList(otherList);` `this` would refer to the instance `c` itself.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) explain what *this* is:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

The keyword `this` refers to the current instance of `CharList`. It is useful for referring to variables that may share the same at class level, otherwise it can be omitted.

Here, no local variable `head` does not appear in the constructor of `CharList`, so can be written as:

```
head = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

> this.head is never used again.

Since `head` is a member variable of the class, the value set in the constructor will be used in other methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "this" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java), but anyway:

It's a reference to the specific instance of the object you're working with. So, if I have (going to write this in C#, sorry):

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(string AString) 
    {
         MyString = AString;
    }

    private string MyString;

    public string WhatsMyStringCalled()
    {
         return this.MyString;
    }
}
```

If I were to construct an instance of MyObject, I would expect WhatsMyStringCalled to return the MyString property associated with that particular instance.