# Java - Why do we use the "this" keyword in constructors?

Tags: java

I've tried to look around but it's hard searching for "this." But I just can't seem to grasp the difference between these two

```
public class x{
int y = 0;
int z = 0;

x(int y, int z){
    y = y;
    z = z
    }
}
```

and

```
public class x{
int y = 0;
int z = 0;

x(int y, int z){
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
   }
}
```

Comment: How else would you differentiate between the `y` parameter and the `y` field of the class?

Comment: It's called [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577575/using-the-keyword-this-in-java

Comment: Because perl had already taken "my" :-)

Answer (score 12):

When you write

```
y = y;
z = z;
```

You're just assigning the local variables to themselves, and not touching the instance variables at all.  Since `y` refers to a local variable, you have to write `this.y` to refer to the instance variable that you want to assign.

You can help to catch mistakes like this by making your variables `final` if they aren't meant to be modified.  For example:

```
x(final int y, final int z) {
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}
```

If you take away the `this.` prefixes, you'll get a compile error because the local variables `y` and `z` can't be changed.

Comment: but I could easily have named the local variables a and b instead; is this the only reason we use the "this" keyword?

Comment: @user3605508 Yes, and even where technically unambiguous, for readability.

Comment: Yes, and some people use a naming convention to prevent instance variable names from conflicting with local variables, such as adding a prefix `m_` or a suffix `_`.  (For example:  `y_ = y;`)

Comment: @user3605508 You're right, you could avoid `this` by doing so.  But doing it using the `this.` is a pretty common idiom, and people will understand what you're doing, and you don't have to try to come up with different names which often just makes things more confusing to a reader.

Comment: @user3605508 what you say is right, but also by using `this` allows for self documenting code.  It is obvious (without comments) that you are assigning to a instance field

Comment: P.S. I think the `_` suffix is out of fashion.  I've seen it only in older books.  (However, Android naming conventions do require private instance variables to start with `m`, so if you follow that convention, you might not use the `this` idiom.)

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `this` keyword represents the current instantiation of the class. So when you create an object:

```
x obj = new x();
```

`x` has two "instance" (not local) variables `y` and `z`.

If your class also has methods that contain local variables of the same name, then how can the Java Runtime environment (the computer) know which `y` and `z` you are referring to? For example:

```
x(int y, int z){
    y = y; //Both z are just the local variables 
           //of this method and don't change the class.
    z = z; //Both z are just the local variables and dont affect class object
}
```

But if you do the following, then you change the objects y value but not its z value:

```
x(int y, int z){
    this.y = 50; //call this function sets the objects y value to 50
    z = z; //But nothing happens to the objects z value because the
           //Java Runtime enviornment sees the z and finds its nearest
           //scope which is the method its defined in and thus the local
           //variable gets set to itself and then deleted after the method
           //is called and the object's z value is not changed.
}
```