# Is the use of the "this" keyword superfluous? Java

Tags: java, object, this

I've been doing some research here and there on the internet, and I think I almost understand how the `this` keyword operates. My question is: When is `this` a necessary function?

I know that it is useful for distinguishing between an Object's private instance variable and another variable that it's being set to if they have the exact same name. Example:

```
public class SomeObject {
    private int someNum;
    public SomeObject() {}
    public setSomeNum(int someNum) {
        this.someNum = someNum;
    }
}
```

I also learned from the second answer @[using-the-keyword-this-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577575/using-the-keyword-this-in-java) that it is used for accessing a "nested" class. Although I have yet to try this out, it appears to be a pretty cool idea.

How this question came to be about: I am writing a `class` that defines game characters from a bunch of attributes:

```
public class Charact {
    private String name;
    // A ton of other private variables that represent character stats.
    public Charact() {} // This one is for the main character.
    public Charact(String name, /*All of the other variable parameters*/) { // This one is used for making NPCs.
        this.name = name;
        // Setting of all of the other variables.
    }    
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    // All of the other getter and setter methods.
}
```

So here's a few questions about my code (that are tangential to my initial question):

Is calling the setter methods with a this, like in `this.setVariable(variable);`, superfluous because it would do the same thing as `setVariable(variable);`?

I specifically declared all of my private instance variables with an uppercase letter, allowing me to avoid the use of `this` in my setters. Is it alright for me to do so (am I breaking any normal naming conventions?) or should I have ought to use lowercase variable names and `this`es in the setters?

Does using `this` somehow help identify which instance of a class is being referred to, or is it already implicit to the computer, meaning that `this` is not really needed?

Any answers that can offer some depth of elaboration would be very helpful, as I've only started making non-static classes this last week. Also, this is my first question, so I am sorry if it doesn't really seem to be asked in the right formatting.

Comment: `public class Character`. Wow buddy.. You might run into a lot of trouble with that *class name*. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is another `Character` class  defined in the jdk :P

Comment: Why? Is it already a preset name for another? Ok then I'll modify it to something like `Charact` in my code. Thanks for the heads up, I've actually heard a little about that class before, just didn't think about when I was writing my class.

Comment: It's a good idea to use `this` when you are referring to instance fields, but in many cases it is *optional*. Also, `private String Name;`. *Please no*. That's totally against Java **naming** convention.

Comment: I use `this` explicitly inside setter methods and constructors. I think this makes the code cleaner.. This is optional though.. And yes, there is a Character class defined by the Java language. You should probably change the name of you class.

Comment: Ahh, yeah that's the general idea of what I was trying to get an answer. Are there many/any cases where it's necessary?

Comment: Invoking overridable methods from constructors is a very bad idea. You should simply use `this.name = name` in your constructor. And respect the Java naming conventions. Variables shouldn't start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: So it is in good practice to make setters with `this`.

Comment: Oh, thanks for answering that one, I wasn't sure if it was malpractice or not to capitalize variables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice JB NIzet, I'll change my code to just initialize the variables rather than use the setters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you already have a grasp on what `this` is for. It is available when you need to be explicit about what you are referring to.

Here is a novel example. (Don't actually write a class like this. It just serves to show usage of `this`.)

```
class Outer {
    int value; /* #1 */

    class Inner {
        int value; /* #2 */

        void setInnerValue(int value /* #3 */) {
            //    #2      #3
            //   vvvvv   vvvvv
            this.value = value;
        }

        void setOuterValue(int value /* #4 */) {
            //          #1      #4
            //         vvvvv   vvvvv
            Outer.this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If there is no need to qualify what you are referencing, then yes it is superfluous.

`this` is also used to invoke constructors in a chain.

```
class Example {
    Example() { this(1); }
    Example(int i) { }
}
```

> am I breaking any normal naming conventions?

Yes, you are. Identifiers in Java start with a lowercase letter by convention (unless they are `static final` constants which are generally all uppercase). You should follow the convention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I've never heard of using a chain like you did with your `class Example`. I am not very practiced in the normal naming conventions yet, but I will do my best to remember to keep my variables lowercase from now on.

Comment: I really like how your first code block explains how `this` is used to call up a variable in many situations. It's Very helpful for me if I begin using nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

calling the setter methods with a this, like in `this.setVariable(variable)` is usually superfluous, but good practise.

Declaring any variables with an uppercase letter is confusing for all other java programmers who might have to maintain your code. We adopt conventions for good reasons. It will confuse you too eventually, when all your variables look like classes, and you can't tell your static calls from instantiated.

`this` is implicitly `this object`.

Edit: above sentence changed from `this class`

Comment: Yes, I see you all are very much so stressing about keeping my code in proper shape. Not sure I understand "tell your static calls from instantiated" but I think I will eventually. Thanks for also mentioning an answer to my setter question.

Comment: *this is implicitly this class*: no. `this` is this **object**.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think I understand the concept.

Comment: agreed, was considering static methods where no object exists, forgetting that `this` is then not there!

Comment: Is it not still possible to call new objects in static classes, and `this` isn't used in the static classes, only in the object classes? Sorry that is one ugly compound question I asked.^

Comment: @CharlieS I agree using keyword `this` _"is usually superfluous, but good practice"_. But could you provide some references (i.e., URLs)

Answer (score 0):

It's handy to use this, because later you will have things like super. and if you don't use super there and don't use this you will end up with messy code.

Comment: We literally just learned about using supers and `extends` in my last class's lecture (Friday). I haven't tried using a superclass in my code, but I can theoretically see what you'd mean by my code appearing messy when I implement that.