# Method overriding in Java. Why is this program not calling the sub class method?

Tags: java

Why is this program not calling the sub class method? What is the concept behind it? I'm totally confused with this.
Below is the code.

Super class

```
public class TV {

     public void checkType(TV b) {
          System.out.println("Its a TV");
     }
}
```

Child class

```
public class LedTv extends TV {

    public void checkType(LedTv b) {
         System.out.println("Its a LED TV");
    }

}
```

Test case to get the result

```
public class TestTV {

    public static void main(String argss[]) {
         TV a = new TV();
         TV b = new LedTv();
         a.checkType(a);
         b.checkType(b);

    }
}
```

Both of the checkType method prints

```
Its a TV
Its a TV
```

Comment: because it´s not overriden, it´s overloaded. You are passing a variable of the type `TV` to the method, hence it´s calling `checkType(TV b)`.

Comment: But why is the second checkType() method printing **Its a TV**

Comment: Because the variable `b` is of type `TV`, not `LedTV` (even though it references to such an object, but that doesn't matter here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class LedTv extends TV {
    @Override //always put this here
    public void checkType() {//no need for argument
        System.out.println("Its a LED TV");
    }

}
```

As you can see from the above example I added an annotation @Override. While this isn't necessary it forces the compiler to check and make sure you are actually overriding something. If you are not you will get an error, which helps solve bugs. The reason I got rid of the argument that you are passing to check type is because it's redundant. you can always use the [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577575/using-the-keyword-this-in-java) keyword to point to the object you are currently inside of.

I realise I forgot to explain what overriding and overloading is so I think this example will show you.

```
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args){
     new Main();
  }

  Main(){
     new SuperClass().method();
     new SuperClass().method(101010);
     new Subclass().method();
     new Subclass().method(595959);
  }

  class SuperClass{

     SuperClass(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
     }

     public void method(){
        System.out.println("method() from SuperClass -> Calling method(int x)");
        method(0);
     }
     public void method(int x){
        System.out.print("method() from SuperClass " + x + "\n\n");
     }
  }
  class Subclass extends SuperClass{
     @Override
     public void method(int x){
        System.out.print("method() from SubClass " + x + "\n\n");
     }
  }

}
```

Output

```
SuperClass
method() from SuperClass -> Calling method(int x)
method() from SuperClass 0

SuperClass
method() from SuperClass 101010

Subclass
method() from SuperClass -> Calling method(int x)
method() from SubClass 0

Subclass
method() from SubClass 595959
```

As you can see in **SuperClass** **method()** is *overloaded* with an int as **method(int x)** and **method()** is *overridden* in **Subclass**. In the output you can clearly see whats going on. [What's the difference between *overloading* a method and overriding it in Java?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164353/whats-the-difference-between-overloading-a-method-and-overriding-it-in-java)

Comment: So you are telling the parameters has no role in which method needs to be called?

Comment: @BhajjiMaga He's saying that you don't pass in the object, since that is the context anyway (`this`). Look at your call `a.checkType(a)`, where you're giving `a` twice. It should be `a.checkType()` with code from this answer.

Comment: @BhajjiMaga There is no need. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html "this" keyword points to itself. maybe you can find other resources on it. I added an example to show you how overloading and overriding works.

Answer (score 3):

Methods get overriden during inheritance when they have the same signature. According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) signature depends on:

1. the method name
2. the number of the arguments
3. the type of the arguments

In your case these methods

```
public void checkType(TV b)
public void checkType(LedTv b)
```

Clearly have different signatures as the type of the argument is different. What you get is called method overloading

Answer (score 0):

overriding method must have the same types for arguments. If you want to override method in subclass it must have the same arguments only return type can be different but from the same hierarchy as in superclass method

Answer (score 0):

`void checkType(TV)` is a different function prototype to `void checkType(LedTv)`.

Therefore you are not *overriding*, but rather you are *overloading*.

For *overriding*, the function name and parameter types must be identical, and the return type *related*. The exact definition of relatedness is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing method overloading. For method overriding both the method signature of the parent and child class should be same. So in the child class instead of this

```
public void checkType(LedTv b) {
     System.out.println("Its a LED TV");
}
```

type this and check -

```
public void checkType(TV b) {
     System.out.println("Its a LED TV");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because both of your objects are of type TV.

```
TV a = new TV();
TV b = new LedTV();
```

is basically the same object base type. In case of creating `b`, all you do is basically telling you want superclass instance with the sub-class functionality as well. And you are overloading the methods, not overriding them. You tell the program if parameter is LedTV, print out this, if parameter is TV, print out this. You are outsourcing the `if-else` logic to the program itself, simply. What you do is

```
if(TV == TV) print TV
else if (TV == LedTV) print LedTV
```

But the problem is both objects are of type TV in your code, so the superclass method is always used and the first if is true, and second one is not even evaluated.

Change b to this:

```
LedTv b = new LedTv();
b.checkType(b);
```

It will now work correctly, because `b` is of type `LedTV`..