# Using "this" to refer to class instance

Tags: java

**Caller.java**

```
ListNode n = new ListNode(5);
```

**ListNode.java**

```
class ListNode{
  int val;
  ListNode next;
   public ListNode(int x){
     val = x;
   }
```

//METHOD

```
 public void print(){
    this.node = node;
     //other
  }
}
```

For every time I do something like

```
ListNode n = new ListNode(5);
n.print();
```

The print method inside `ListNode.java` has a `this`, which only refers to that new instance? (`n` in this case)

Comment: Yes yes yes yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the keyword "this" in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577575/using-the-keyword-this-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The word `this` refers to the actual instance. In this case `this` refers to `n` reference. You have an auto relationship in your class. So, maybe you have misspelled `this.node = node` instead of `this.next = node` or something like that. In this case, each instance (n and next inside n) have its own scopes represented by `this` keyword inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct.

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html